# Set value in separate pandas column when mapping dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dictionary:

```
d = {"A":1, "B":2, "C":3}
```

I also have a pandas dataframe:

```
col1
A
G
E
B
C
```

I'd like to create a new column by mapping the dictionary onto `col1`. Simultaneously I'd like to set the values in another column to indicate whether the value in that row has been mapped. The desired output would look like this:

```
col1    col2    col3
A       1       1
G       NaN     0
E       NaN     0
B       2       1
C       3       1
```

I know that `col2` can be created using `df.col1.map(d)`, but how can I simultaneously create `col3`?

Comment: `how can I simultaneously create col3` - not 100% sure what you think, can you explain more?

Answer (score 1):

You can create both column in one function [`assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) - first by `map` and second by [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) for boolean mask with casting to `integers`:

```
df = df.assign(col2=df.col1.map(d), col3=df.col1.isin(d.keys()).astype(int))
print (df)
  col1  col2  col3
0    A   1.0     1
1    G   NaN     0
2    E   NaN     0
3    B   2.0     1
4    C   3.0     1
```

Another 2 step solution with different boolean mask - by checking not missing values:

```
df['col2'] = df.col1.map(d)
df['col3'] = df['col2'].notnull().astype(int)
```